# Is there syntactic sugar for binding a value inside an anonymous function in Scala?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, syntactic-sugar

Instead of writing

```
((x: Double) => (((y: Double) => y*y))(x+x))(3)
```

I would like to write something like

```
((x: Double) => let y=x+x in y*y)(3)
```

Is there anything like this sort of syntactic sugar in Scala?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed there is: it's called "`val`".  :-)

```
({ x: Double =>
  val y = x + x
  y * y
})(3)
```

The braces are of course optional here, I just prefer them to parentheses when defining functions (after all, this isn't Lisp).  The `val` keyword defines a new binding within the current lexical scope.  Scala doesn't force locals to define their own scope, unlike languages such as Lisp and ML.

Actually, `var` also works within any scope, but it's considered bad style to use it.

Comment: Thanks :) I thought I had tried that, but I must have gotten the syntax wrong. Is there a way to have it all in one line?

Comment: @Germán has the one-line version.

Answer (score 6):

OK, here's the one liner WITH the binding:

```
 ({ x:Double => val y = x + x; y * y })(3)
```

Cheers